# Outlook REST API - ErrorItemNotFound error when requesting user details, but not other endpoints

Tags: outlook-restapi

Using the Outlook REST API, I am trying to get the details for a particular user.  Using any of the `GET /api/v1.0/users/{email@domain.com}`, `GET /api/v2.0/users/{email@domain.com}`, `GET /api/v1.0/me` or `GET /api/v2.0/me` endpoints, I am receiving the following 404 response:

```
{
  "error": {
     "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
     "message": "The requested user '{email@domain.com}' is invalid."
  }
}
```

An example response header for this failed request is the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
request-id: 1f11b407-5c2d-4c9b-b2aa-af837367cad4
X-CalculatedFETarget: CY4PR19CU002.internal.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 404
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie={hidden}; expires=Fri, 19-Jan-2018 14:43:02 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
X-FEProxyInfo: CY4PR19CA0037.NAMPRD19.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
X-CalculatedBETarget: CY4PR10MB1542.namprd10.prod.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 404
OData-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-DiagInfo: CY4PR10MB1542
X-BEServer: CY4PR10MB1542
X-FEServer: CY4PR19CA0037
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: BN3PR04CA0035
Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 14:43:01 GMT
```

The request also includes the `X-AnchorMailbox`, `Authorization` and `Accept` headers. I am seeing the same error message returned if I try any of the above endpoints with the `X-AnchorMailbox` header removed from the request.

I have a valid Oauth access token for the user as well as a valid Oauth refresh token.  I can successfully refresh the user's access token and I am also able to successfully call other endpoints for the user, such as:

```
GET /api/v1.0/Me/Contacts

GET /api/v1.0/me/folders

GET /api/v1.0/me/folders/{folderId}/childfolders

GET /api/v1.0/me/folders/{folderId}/messages
```

Again, each of these requests also include the `X-AnchorMailbox`, `Authorization` and `Accept` headers.

An example response header for a successful request is the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
request-id: 4225f4c7-9933-4252-9e03-79f607957181
X-CalculatedFETarget: CY4PR19CU002.internal.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie={hidden}; expires=Fri, 19-Jan-2018 14:43:37 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
X-FEProxyInfo: CY4PR19CA0043.NAMPRD19.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
X-CalculatedBETarget: CY4PR10MB1542.namprd10.prod.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200
OData-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-DiagInfo: CY4PR10MB1542
X-BEServer: CY4PR10MB1542
X-FEServer: CY4PR19CA0043
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: BN3PR04CA0008
Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 14:43:37 GMT
```

Why would I get the 404 on the users endpoint, indicating that the user is invalid, but be able to successfully receive the user's data from the other endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the users details using `/Me` API as well. `/Me` API is just a short cut for the currently authenticated user. So in case the authenticated user and user in `Users('email@domain')` are same you can just use `Me`.

I believe that you are not trying to access the same user in case of `Me` and `Users`, and that is why the API is complaining or the email address you are using in users doesn't belong to the same tenant that you have gotten the token for.

Comment: Thank you Yogesh.  I have also tried the /api/v2.0/me and /api/v1.0/me endpoints, both with the X-AnchorMailbox header and without.  All of these requests return the same error as the one I listed above:  {"error":{"code":"ErrorItemNotFound","message":"The requested user '{email@domain.com}' is invalid."}}.  Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue I am seeing.

Comment: I have updated my question to indicate that I'm seeing the same behavior with the "me" endpoints.

Comment: Provide all response headers for successful and unsuccessful request, for the same user.

Comment: I have provided sample response headers for a failed request as well as a successful request

Comment: From the logs, it looks like you are trying to access a Shared Mailbox, is that true?

Comment: I am not sure of that, as I do not know the details of this person's setup.  This is coming from a user who has authorized our application to connect to their MS account.  The call to the "users" endpoint was working up until mid-day on Jan 17th, at which point we started to see this error in our logs.  Why would the "users" or "me" endpoint return a 404 if the account was set up with sharing?  Is it possible that the user's account has been disabled, or would all of the other API calls fail as well in that case?

Comment: I will investigate this further

Comment: just wondering if you've been able to spend any more time on this one.  Thank you.